# What's the most efficient way to get D8 to notice changes to .yml files?

Tags: 8

I'm taking my first steps with Drupal 8, starting with a custom theme. As a result I'm making incremental changes and testing them.

I've found that in order to be able to tweak CSS you have to turn off aggregation. The normal: *change css, `drush cc css-js`, reload page* workflow doesn't work unless aggregation is disabled.

But I'm also having difficulty with Drupal not picking up changes to the yaml files, e.g. add css to the THEME.libraries.yml file - no `drush cc ...` command has any effect. The only thing I've found to work is `drush cr` (or `drupal cache:rebuild`) which adds about 20-30s delay in my workflow.

Is there a quicker workflow for development?

Comment: 20-30 seconds is insane, all of my D8 sites rebuild cache within a couple seconds. Maybe it's a problem with drupal console, try using `drush cr all`

Comment: `time drush cr all: 10.69s user 0.26s system 63% cpu 17.123 total`. And then the next page load takes ages, too of course. That's on a VM with 4Gb RAM and 2 cores and SSD drives, 2 nodes(!) and nothing else. `time drupal cache:rebuild all  11.38s user 0.29s system 62% cpu 18.678 total`

Comment: 2-3x quicker is certainly an improvement, but 10+ seconds is still odd in my experience. Try giving the VM more resources to check if that's the issue

Comment: Where did you get that 2-3x from? drush cr all took 17s life seconds, `drupal` took 18s. More resources is not an option.

Comment: `time drush cr all: 10.69s` 30/10 ~= 3

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. `time sleep 1: 0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 1.003 total` - it's the last number you need to look at, not the first (user time). So it's about 17-18s by either method, plus then you have the delay of several seconds when you first refresh the page after a `cr`, hence my "20-30s"

Comment: Ah ok my bad - the delay on first page load is expected, but 17s isn't right. Tuning the VM would be the next job I think, or profiling the cache rebuild to see where the bottleneck is. Maybe your storage is NFS or something and causing a delay? Difficult to give advice without being able to get to the server and see what's wrong

Comment: OK, will check out performance bottlenecks. Sounds like I'm doing the right (only) thing, just have a slow VM.

Comment: Do you have a fancy version of `time` BTW? I just executed a cr all on OSX, Debian and CentOS - none of them are formatted like your output. I get, e.g. `real 0m4.545s user 0m2.768s sys 0m0.431s` on every platform, no `total`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36693/discussion-between-artfulrobot-and-clive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your development.services.yml file turn twig cache off and debug true. This will assist in theming, twig files are also cached.

Secondly, I think the command you want for yml changes is drush cr. However if they are install yml files, (I believe) they'd only register when a theme is enabled/uninstalled like modules are. So if that's the case you'd need to do that. I've also needed to use cr with libraries.yml changes.

Third, what VM are you using? I can run drush cr and it only takes ~5 seconds on the DrupalVM stack.

Comment: Thanks for tips. drush cr and drupal (console) cache:rebuild are the same thing. cr stands for cache rebuild... And they perform the same - see my comment (which also covers some VM details)

Comment: Right but what version of php, how much php memory, all that stuff? Is it a vanilla VM or specifically tuned LAMP stack?

Comment: That's not what you've put in your question @artfulrobot - `drupal cache:rebuild` isn't Drush, completely different bit of software, they might produce different results. May not be the problem, but it's good to be clear

Comment: The commands may have the same purpose, but I haven't looked to see if they do the same thing. Console is still brand new and I have found it to be buggy, drush will be my tool until they pull the plug on it.

Comment: @clive Sorry for "are the same". What I meant was that they are supposed to do the same thing; they achieve the same result (changes are noticeable) and they take the same time to do it.  Have edited Q.

Answer (score 2):

[Configuration Development](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_devel) does several helpful things for Configuration Management. Among them, the one you need is:

> Automated import of configuration files into the active storage. At
>   the beginning of every request the changed files are saved the way as
>   if it were dumped in the core config module provided "Single import"
>   form.

This means that instead of reading your YAML configuration only when you enable your module, Drupal will reload changes on runtime.